# Add new record edit form not displaying with dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Does anyone one why this line is preventing the edit form of a Telerik RadGrid from displaying when I click "add new record"? The edit form displays normally when I click edit on a row.

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="lst_ProjectCode" 
        class="form-control" 
        runat="server" Width="250" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
        DataValueField="ProjectCode" 
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProjectCode")%>'>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

It is something to do with the `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProjectCode")%>'` as otherwise it the edit form comes up. Is it because this value is blank?

Comment: Does `SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProjectCode") %>'` work?

Comment: How does your grid code looks?